# "Lançamento Novo" ou "Novo Lançamento" são iguais?

Tags: adjetivos, ordem-de-expressões

Estávamos em uma discussão sobre a utilização dessas expressões:

> Lançamento Novo

ou

> Novo Lançamento

Alguma delas é correta? Se sim, elas tem sentido diferente uma em relação a outra?

---

Essa frase faz sentido?

> Os **novos** lançamentos fizeram um sucesso maior que os **antigos** lançamentos.

Comment: Bom ponto. Parecem mais pleonasmos.

Comment: Justamente, entramos nesta discussão, pois alguns acham ser pleonasmo, outros não.

Comment: "[Sentença](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/senten%C3%A7a)"??

Comment: Alterei, digitei com um pouco de pressa

Comment: @ANeves e Lucas: O que são os lançamentos de que estão a falar? Lançamento de um produto? Isto é, a sua apresentação e promoção junto do público?

Comment: Eu não falei de lançamento nenhum, @Jacinto . O LucasMotta parece falar de lançamentos de produtos, sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tenho a sensação de que existe sim uma diferença de significado entre as duas variações no Brasil, e que por isso mesmo "novo lançamento" é muito mais ouvido  que "lançamento novo". Eu vejo um deslocamento do sentido do adjetivo quando ele vem antes do substantivo a que se refere.

Compare, por exemplo, *um novo homem* e *um homem novo*. A diferença de sentido é clara. No primeiro, *novo* significa *renovado*, e no segundo, significa *jovem*. O adjetivo anteposto ganha mais ênfase e o sentido de novidade (do que não havia antes, do que existe há pouco tempo) é intensificado. O *renovado* é o que é novo *outra vez*, *novo de novo*.

Os redatores de propagandas sabem que podem conquistar o consumidor enfatizando aquilo que ele busca, e o "novo" é uma das coisas mais desejadas e valorizadas na sociedade contemporânea. Quando os anúncios dizem *novo lançamento*, estão enfatizando *novo*, dizendo que "o meu novo é mais novo que o dos outros", ao ponto de muitas vezes serem literais: *o mais novo lançamento*. A duração das novidades anda tão curta, que o sentido da palavra *lançamento* está enfraquecendo, precisando ser reforçado a um nível que pode até ser visto como pleonástico.

Sobre as construções serem corretas ou não, não conheço norma que trate disso. Mas certamente são ambas gramaticais, e pelo menos a primeira variação ocorre bastante no Brasil. A segunda forma é menos comum, mas seria plenamente compreensível dependendo do contexto em que estiver. Aliás, o mesmo vale para o seu exemplo dos novos *versus* antigos lançamentos. Acho perfeitamente compreensível, e o contexto pode eliminar o ar de estranheza que a frase solta causa.

Answer (score -1):

O significado é o mesmo, não vejo diferença entre as duas formas. No Brasil a forma mais comum é "um novo lançamento".  Raramente ouvimos "um lançamento novo".  Claro, é um pleonasmo, como alguém comentou, da mesma forma que "uma surpresa inesperada", "duas metades iguais" ou "elo de ligação"  São pleonasmos mas são ouvidos com frequência.

Comment: Não é bem pleonasmo porque as construtoras usam "lançamento" significando qualquer empreendimento que não tenha sido totalmente vendido ainda :P

Comment: @bfavaretto Se eu disser que cortei o queijo **em duas metades iguais** e os tamanhos não forem iguais, isso não anula o pleonasmo da minha fala.

Comment: Ok, não vou discutir se é pleonasmo ou não porque isso não importa. Me interessa mais (próclise!) investigar o motivo desse pleonasmo ocorrer tanto no Brasil. A palavra "lançamento" está perdendo o sentido de novidade, talvez porque a novidade esteja sendo banalizada. Há "lançamentos" e "novidades" a todo momento em todo lugar, há uma supervalorização do novo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Todos nós usamos  figuras de linguagem, inclusive pleonasmos, ocasionalmente.  Eu, pelo menos, descubro vez por outra um termo que eu vinha usando e que é um pleonasmo.  Lembro que só há cerca de 10 anos é que fui me dar conta que "surpresa inesperada" é um pleonasmo.  Quanto ao pronome em próclise, aprendi no ginásio (sim, naquela época chamava-se ginásio) que não se começa uma frase com pronome oblíquo em próclise. Pode ser que tenha mudado desde então.

Comment: Não mudou. A norma culta dita ênclise nesse caso. Mas eu muitas vezes opto por violar a norma culta e aproximar a escrita da linguagem falada, especialmente em comentários, por achar natural a informalidade que isso carrega.

Comment: Digamos que ocorreram dois lançamentos em momentos diferentes. Se alguém disser apenas `lançamento` não fica claro se trata do primeiro ou do segundo lançamento. Já se alguém disser `novo lançamento` fica claro que se trata do segundo lançamento. Neste caso não é pleonasmo.

Comment: Essa é a situação, é pleonasmo, mas sem o pleonasmo a frase perderia um pouco do sentido, ou tornaria o entendimento mais complicado

Comment: "downvote"?  Sem explicar o porquê?  Não é a melhor atitude.